# Why i cannot show popup on some websites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i made a chrome extension, and my extension will show popup on webpage. I create popup by div tag  like this:

```
var myPopupDiv = document.createElement('div');
myPopupDiv.className = "popup";
document.body.appendChild(myPopupDiv);
```

And css for popup class as following:

```
div.popup {
color: #fafafa !important;
border-color: #000000 !important;
border-width: 0px !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
background-color: #363636 !important;
font-size: 16px !important;
padding: 8px !important;
overflow: visible !important;
z-index: 999999 !important;
text-align: left  !important;
cursor: default;
position: absolute !important;
}
```

I dont know why my popup sometimes show up on some pages and sometimes it is not shown up on some others. For a specific case, my popup cannot be shown up when my extension work on stackoverflow webpage.

what is wrong with my javascript code?how can i make a popup display on any webpages?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked, and StackOverflow's CSS defines a `popup` class with `display: none`.  Use the Chrome "Inspect Element" panel to check if your div is added to the DOM, and if it got the `display: none` style applied.  I'd fix this by coming up with a unique name for your  CSS class.

Comment: thanks for yr reply, it works when i change the name of css class.